# Change CakeEmail SMTP authentication type

Tags: php, email, cakephp, authentication, smtp

How do you change the authentication type that CakeEmail uses when using Smtp transport?

I get this error: `SMTP Error: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type` when trying to send to a system that doesn't support Password authentication. It only supports NTLM. I haven't seen anything about setting the authentication type in the cookbook or API for CakePHP 2.5.1. Is there any way to manually change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHPs [**SMTP transport**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-SmtpTransport.html) only supports basic username/password [**authentication**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.1/lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php#L192), there are no other authentication types implemented, and there's also no specialized mechanism for plugging in authentication adapters or the like.

So you'll probably have to create a custom/extended SMTP transport.

I'm not familiar with NTLM, but judging from the [**RFC**](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/ntlm.html#ntlmSmtpAuthentication) it should be possible to plug-in an implementation of the [**NTLM authentication flow**](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/ntlm.html#ntlmSmtpAuthentication) in an overridden `SmtpTransport::_auth()` method.